# Lenovo Ideapad 320-15IAP Secure Boot option not available in BIOS setup

Tags: lenovo-laptop, secure-boot

[image: BIOS setup utility on IdeaPad 320-15IAP]I recently bought a Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IAP (running Windows 10, with an Intel Pentium N4200 quad-core processor). Upon trying to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows partition, I kept getting a GRUB installer crash error. After some investigation I realized that Windows Secure Boot must be disabled in order to install the boot loader.

Here's the problem: When I open the BIOS setup utility and go to the Security tab, there is no option to disable Secure Boot.

Does this model not support dual-boot installation, or is there some way I can disable Secure Boot that I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boot - Enable only UEFI. -> F10 -> Enter (Save change and reboot)
Enter the BIOS again and in Security you see Secure boot settings)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).